# Spring Integration Ftp | how to test code for move remote files into another directory in remote server after FTP fetch complete

Tags: junit, ftp, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-ftp

We have a remote FTP server in which we have a folder "test/" which contains certain text files. The "test/" folder has another subdirectory "archive/" inside it.

FTPserver->
-test/
---abc.txt
---xyz.txt
---archive/

We are able to download all the text files via Spring Integration flows in our local directory and move the file into another remote location on same ftp server. Now we are looking into ways to test the below working code.

**Working Code:**

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {            
        File localDirectory = new File("tmp/");
        FtpInboundChannelAdapterSpec ftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec = Ftp.inboundAdapter(gimmeFactory())
                .remoteDirectory("test/")
                .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true)
                .regexFilter(".*\\.txt$")
                .localDirectory(localDirectory)
                .preserveTimestamp(true)
                .remoteFileSeparator("/");
        
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(ftpInboundChannelAdapterSpec, e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(Duration.ofSeconds(5))))
                .handle(Ftp.outboundGateway(gimmeFactory(), AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.LS, "'test/'")
                        .options(AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Option.NAME_ONLY))
                .split()
                .handle(Ftp.outboundGateway(gimmeFactory(), AbstractRemoteFileOutboundGateway.Command.MV, "'test/' +payload").renameExpression("'test/archive/' +payload"))
                .channel("nullChannel")
                .get();
}
```

I have gone through many articles but not able to get the exact solution for this. Can anyone please help me here for to test the above working code. Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

The framework uses Apache Mina for integration tests; you can do the same.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/main/spring-integration-ftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/ftp/FtpTestSupport.java#L56

Comment: Thanks @GaryRussell for the help, Actually we are using the mockFTP server that we are initiating in the (@Before) setup() mehtod...now the issue is that when we are trying to write the test case with (@SpringBootTest),the Integration flow code that is given like above example runs before the setup of the MockFTP server in the (@before) annotated method..so our mockFTP server starts after the Integration flow has ended...
is there an alternate way to test the Specific Integration flow as given in this post ?

Comment: See the testing appendix in the documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#testing and specifically https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/testing.html#test-context which shows how to prevent a flow from starting, allowing you to inject messages into the flow.